# Converting a for loop to a while loop ( with a range involved)

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, while-loop

Converting this to a while loop is turning out to be more trouble than initially thought.
Any tips or tricks on how to solve this would be appreciated

```
sum = 0
for i in range (10,0,-1):
    sum = sum +1
    print(i,sum)
```

this is as close as i can get -

```
i=1
while i in range(10,0,-1):
    print(i)
    print(i, end=' ')
    i=i+1
```

the hard part seems to be the range numbers
this is a specific questions ( i know a for loop is a better solution than a while loop)

Comment: You increment `i` but use a decrementing range. Start with the max and subtract 1 on each loop. Use a separate counter for the sum. Also, simpler than a range, just compare `i` to the bounds.

Comment: Yeah im 6 weeks into a python intro course and have no idea what's going on.

Comment: Get a pen a paper, break it down step by step

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your guess was too close to get the same result using while loop.
Use two , len() and list() function , to get the same outputs.

```
i=1
while i in range(10,0,-1):
print(len(list(range(10,0,-1)))-i+1,i)
i=i+1
```

Thankyou hope it helps

Comment: Awesome, I understand this one. cheers

Answer (score 0):

I think this code will do what you expect

```py
s = i = 10
while i > 0:
    print(i, s-i+1)
    i=i-1
```

note: Unless you have a very specific reason to use variable names that have the same name as built-in functions, it is recommended to use a variable name that does not interfere with built-in function names. In the code you provided in the question, the built-in `sum` function is overwritten with an integer value. Check out the list of built-in names: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html